# How to access the Zoom settings in iOS Simulator? (listed in search, but not visible)

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I'd like to access the Zoom settings in the iOS Simulator (v17.2, iPhone).
When I search for "zoom" in the Settings app, appropriate result are shown. Tapping on one of the results leads to the "Accessibility" section, but "Zoom" is not available.

Does anyone know, whether the Zoom settings are available in a simulator and how I can see them?

Some screenshots:

Searching "zoom" in simulator:

[image: Searching zoom in simulator]

Zoom is nowhere in "Accessibility" in simulator:

[image: No Zoom in Accessibility in simulator]

This is how it looks on a device:

[image: Zoom setting entry on a device]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessibility Zoom is not available in Simulators. You can use Developer -> Display Zoom (View) -> Large Text. It will ask to confirm if you want to use Zoomed display view.

Comment: Actually I have a problem where I cannot move app icons on the simulator's home screen and some suggest to adjust some zoom feature settings. But indeed it looks like Zoom is not available on simulators, although it appears in the search results.

Comment: Even though simulators seem to be designed as a virtual hardware environment, they have limitations in terms of certain actions and some hardware related functionalities - aka Bluetooth, Wifi, camera, mic, location access. You would need your own Apple device soon or late if you are a tester or developer.